# PDF template shows wrong font when populated by iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext

We have an application where our clients use Adobe Acrobat to create a pdf template for a completion certificate. When a user completes the requirements our application fills in the defined fields and allows them to print the certificate. One of the certificates is printing in Arial (Helvetica) instead of the requested font in some (but not all) of the fields.

I have checked all the relevent links in Stack Overflow and other sites but none of them address the failure of a template to display the font defined in the field.

Code snippet:

```
        var pdfStream = new MemoryStream();

        var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, pdfStream);

        var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
        var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(new HostConfig().GetConfigRoot().GetParent().FullName + "\\fonts\\ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        pdfFormFields.AddSubstitutionFont(baseFont);

        foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfData) {
            if (de.Key != null && de.Value != null) {
                var foundField = pdfFormFields.SetField(de.Key.ToString(), de.Value.ToString());
                if (foundField) {
                    pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty(de.Key.ToString(), "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
                    pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty(de.Key.ToString(), "flags", PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT, null);
                    pdfFormFields.RegenerateField(de.Key.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
        pdfStamper.Close();
        pdfStream.Close();
        return pdfStream;
```

Using resharper debugger to inspect the Acro fields shows that they all have the following in the hashMap of the field widget:

> [{/DA}]     {/MonotypeCorsiva 40 Tf 0 g}
>   (font size varies in different fields)

The fields that revert to Arial also contain the following in the hashMap:

> [{/DR}]     {Dictionary}

which when expanded contains:

> [{/Helv}]   {67 0 R}

The problem persists even when removing pdfFormFields.AddSubstitutionFont.  None of the fields contain any glyphs or charaters other than the common Latin character set.

Another interesting effect is that if FormFlattening is not set to true, you can click on the fields in Acrobat Reader and they display as MonotypeCorsiva until you move the focus elsewhere.

---

Additional Information:

We are looking into fixing the document. I am not free post the template without permission because it belongs to our client.

Comment: The easiest way to fix this, is to fix the form. If that is not an option, it will be hard to provide an answer without having the form to experiment with. Have you posted this question on [our ticketing system](https://jira.itextsupport.com/)? (If so, I can't find it.)

Comment: Please share the PDF in question. Without it this amounts to pure guesswork.